# Does CassandraTemplate.insert excute a cassandra logged batch?

Tags: spring-data-cassandra

Checking spring data Cassandra, It catch my attention that if I use the method `cassandraTemplate.insert(List)`, it does behind an 
     `org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.CassandraTemplate.doBatchWrite`
I am wondering if this a batch Cassandra. So my insert is actually cql insert batch.

Here the full stack

```
at org.springframework.cassandra.core.CqlTemplate.doExecute(CqlTemplate.java:278)
       at org.springframework.cassandra.core.CqlTemplate.doExecute(CqlTemplate.java:559)
       at org.springframework.cassandra.core.CqlTemplate.execute(CqlTemplate.java:1313)
       at org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.CassandraTemplate.doBatchWrite(CassandraTemplate.java:766)
       at org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.CassandraTemplate.doBatchInsert(CassandraTemplate.java:744)
       at org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.CassandraTemplate.insert(CassandraTemplate.java:280)
       at org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.CassandraTemplate.insert(CassandraTemplate.java:275)
       at com.kinaxia.dmu.batch.utils.CassandraItemWriter.write(CassandraItemWriter.java:28)
```

Comment: Well it seems that the answer is yes. As it shows in the code of the version 1.5.X ( the version I use ) spring data creates a batch object in this line

Comment: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-cassandra/blob/1.5.x/spring-data-cassandra/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/cassandra/core/CassandraTemplate.java#L970